# Emit at a certain position doesn't work?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to emit particles at a certain position without having to move the Particle System. I found this: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.EmitParams-position.html

I tried that, but it doesn't emit at the position I want instead it emits them at 0,0,0 where particle emitter is located!

```
   var emitParams = new ParticleSystem.EmitParams();
                emitParams.position = keyValue.Key;
                emitParams.velocity = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
                SmokeParticles.Emit(emitParams, 100);
```

keyValue.key is a vector that holds the correct position. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Unity editor has a lot of attributes in the Particle System setup, one of which is "play on awake", which makes sure the particle system is on from the start. You could simply put:

```
SmokeParticles.Stop();
```

Before the override code section, and then the (0,0,0) particle system will be turned off. The Emit call you make should show the position you chose. For testing purposes, I would also add to the EmitParams:

```
emitParams.startColor = Color.red;
```

Just to highlight the override emission.

Also, for repeating emissions (to better reproduce the original result) have a look at this example from the documentation:

[Particle System Emit Documentation.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.Emit.html)

Comment: sorry but that did nothing, as I mentioned in the thread I used the documentation and it failed to work. I stopped the particles and now I see nothing.

Comment: Interesting. I did it in my system to test, and I could see the red particles I created without the (0,0,0) particle system. Where is the code you wrote placed? Which method and which script?

Comment: inside a function that is called from update if certain requirements are met. the code is exactly the same as the one I sent, and to test I also played the particlesystem on the position and it worked correctly. but sadly just emitting at a position didnt.. perhaps the problem is because i try to emit many particles at almost the same time in different positions, did you success in doing that?

Comment: I succeeded in emitting both the regular system and the extra override particles at the same time... The question now is to debug the flow - are you certain the criteria is met and the code block is invoked? Could you add debug logs?

Comment: yes. Im 100% Certain, what should I add debug? I can share the whole script but it is very messy and unreadble. I'm trying to create fire particles appearing at random places where there suppost to be fire. The positions are 100% correct

Comment: Of course. Simply add 'Debug.log(keyValue.Key);' right before the SmokeParticles.Emit(emitParams,100) line. It will show up in the console with the locations and confirm the code is getting there.

Comment: the debug showed them displaying at the right position yet they didnt show up. Ended up using multiple particle systems. Thanks anyways for the attempt at helping.

Comment: It's fascinating. I'm glad I could be of service, and I'm curious how our results differed.

Comment: No clue. Unrelated to that, תודה על העזרה רק עכשיו שמתי לב שאתה ישראלי :).

Comment: על לא דבר :-) יש סיכוי שתקבל את התשובה שלי, אגב? זה רק ללחוץ על הוי האפור משמאל.